# Add padding to page from a separate component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a sticky cta component. I need padding on the bottom of the Main Page its on so it doesn't cover the footer when the user reaches the end of the page.

How can I do this in the cta component itself? Or not have code all over the place (adding css logic on the page separate from the component) making it hard to maintain?

```
export function Page() {
  return (
    <div className={`stickyCta ? "mb-50": ""`}> //want a different solution for THIS!!
      <h1>Hello React.</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
       <StickyCta />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```
export function StickyCta() {
  return (
    <div className="fixed bottom-0 left-0 right-0">
      <h1>get mine now</>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: incorrect cta position. covering footer]

[image: Needs to add padding to page so cta can go below]

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an empty block-level div with an absolute height before the fixed div:

```
export function StickyCta() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="h-[100px]"></div>
      <div className="fixed bottom-0 left-0 right-0">
        <h1>get mine now</h1>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```